# How to open custom port in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I deploy rabbit mq on cluster, so far running well on port 15672 : http://test.website.com/

but there need open some other ports (25672, 15672, 15674). I has defined in yaml like this :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  selector:
    name: rabbitmq
  ports:
   - port: 80
     name: http
     targetPort: 15672
     protocol: TCP
   - port: 443
     name: https
     targetPort: 15672
     protocol: TCP

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbitmq
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      name: rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: rabbitmq
          image: rabbitmq:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 15672
              name: http
              protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  hosts:
  -  “test.website.com”
  gateways:
  - gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 80
        host: rabbitmq
```

How do I setup in yaml file to open some other ports ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by whitelisting? Did you try a Service?

Comment: Clarification: you can't  `telnet test.website.com 5672` from running pod?

Comment: Check with your network or security team on any outbound firewall

Comment: Hi @Rico I just update the description..

Comment: Hi @AlexYu I just update the description..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Istio [Gateway](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#Gateway) is serving TCP network connections, you might be able to combine one `Gateway` configuration for two external ports.

Here is an example:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: port1
      protocol: TCP
    hosts:
    - example.myhost.com
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: port2
      protocol: TCP
    hosts:
    - example.myhost.com
```

Field `hosts` identifies here a list of target addresses that have to be exposed by this `Gateway`.

In order to make appropriate network routing to the nested Pods specify [VirtualService](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#VirtualService) with the matching set for the ports:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-virtual-service
spec:
  hosts:
  - example.myhost.com 
  gateways:
  - gateway
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
        host: app.example.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 15672
  - match:
    - port: 443
    route:
    - destination:
        host: app.example.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 15674
```

Above `VirtualService` defines the rules to route network traffic coming on 80 and 443 ports for `test.website.com` to the `rabbitmq` service ports 15672, 15674 respectively.

You can adjust these files to your needs to open some other ports.

Take a look: [virtualservice-for-a-service-which-exposes-multiple-ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492068/how-to-configure-istios-virtualservice-for-a-service-which-exposes-multiple-por).