# How to use Istio Ingress to forward STOMP protocol of RabbitMQ in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I tried with this `Gateway`, and `VirtualService`, didn't work.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: stomp
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: stomp
      protocol: TCP
    hosts:
    - rmq-stomp.mycompany.com
```

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: rmq-stomp
spec:
  hosts:
  - rmq-stomp.mycompany.com
  gateways:
  - stomp
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 61613
        host: rabbitmq.default.svc.cluster.local
```

There's no problem with the service, because when I tried to connect from other pod, it's connected.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tcp.match`, not `http.match`. Here is the example I have found in [istio gateway docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/) and in [istio virtualservice dosc](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#TCPRoute)

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-mongo
  namespace: bookinfo-namespace
spec:
  hosts:
  - mongosvr.prod.svc.cluster.local # name of internal Mongo service
  gateways:
  - some-config-namespace/my-gateway # can omit the namespace if gateway is in same namespace as virtual service.
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 27017
    route:
    - destination:
        host: mongo.prod.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 5555
```

So your would look sth like:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: rmq-stomp
spec:
  hosts:
  - rmq-stomp.mycompany.com
  gateways:
  - stomp
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
        host: rabbitmq.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 61613
```

---

Here is a similar question answered: [how-to-configure-istios-virtualservice-for-a-service-which-exposes-multiple-por](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492068/how-to-configure-istios-virtualservice-for-a-service-which-exposes-multiple-por)